# How to enable Internet Connection Sharing via a script?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ics

I have two NIC ports [`port1` & `port2`] and want to enable Internet Connection Sharing on `port1` through either C# or batch script:

- I have only been able to find how to start the ICS service, not to enable the option: 
   [image: Screenshot1]

Answer (score 0):

On earlier OS versions, `netsh routing` could be used, but this no longer works in Win7.

- Have a look at this Powershell snip, otherwise StackOverflow likely has a C# example:

  ```powershell
  # Register the HNetCfg library (once)
    RegSvr32 "hnetcfg.dll"

  # Create a NetSharingManager object
    $m = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare

  # List connections
    $m.EnumEveryConnection |% { $m.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_) }

  # Find connection
    $c = $m.EnumEveryConnection |? { $m.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_).Name -eq "Ethernet" }

  # Get sharing configuration
    $config = $m.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.Invoke($c)

  # See if sharing is enabled
    Write-Output $config.SharingEnabled

  # See the role of connection in sharing, only meaningful if SharingEnabled is True
    # 0: Public || 1: Private
    Write-Output $config.SharingType

  # Enable sharing
    # 0: Public || 1: Private
    $config.EnableSharing(0)

  # Disable sharing
    $config.DisableSharing()
  ```
- [How to enable Internet Connection Sharing using command line?](https://superuser.com/q/470319/529800)

Comment: not wokring on win8.1