# How to share internet using command prompt?

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, boot, laptop

How to share the internet (first checkbox) from the command prompt?

[image]

Comment: In Windows 10, try (from a command prompt) netsh wlan connect .  This can connect to an existing profile . Type netsh wlan connect /?  to see the help for this. There is a netsh wlan disconnect command as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Internet Connection Sharing using command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/470319/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line)